# Cordova 3 without Windows 8 support?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I try to deploy my existing PhonGap 2.3.0 project to Windows Surface RT (8/8.1). I found a lib for windows 8.

I also took a look at PhoneGap/Cordova 3.0.0 but it seems there isn't a target to win8 anymore, only wp8. I installed Cordova via nodejs, I didn't found another way.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're confused about what features are supported on what environments, make sure to read the [Platform Support](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_overview_index.md.html#Overview).  It gives details about what is supported where.

It appears from the picture you posted you might be using Cordova CLI, which from the document I linked, does not support Windows 8.

Comment: I am a confused. http://phonegap.com/install/ means downloading and installing phonegap CLI by nodejs (without win8) and http://cordova.apache.org/#download means downloading phonegap SDK (with win8)?